Raspberry 5: Raspberry Pi OS 64 - black screen with blinking cursor
Blank New Raspberry 5. When I insert an SD card (tried with different) with Raspberry OS
64-bit, it shows a loading screen, then switches to a black screen with a blinking cursor.
When I start with 32-bit OS, it works fine, except it doesn't want to install rpi-connect (it doesn't want to install dependencies such as python3 amd64, etc.)
umap shows amd64 chip.
What's wrong and how can it be fixed (preferably 64bit os)?

Which OS was installed? How was it installed; i.e. RPi Imager??

Yes, RPI Imager v1.8.5, Installed Raspbery PI (64 bit) 2024-03-15 (that gave a black screen with cursor) and same, but 32 bit.

Are you using a 4K screen? What resolution? Have you got another you can try?

Sometimes, existing packages might conflict with the new ones. Remove any conflicting packages and try again.

@liaifat85 as i mentioned, this is a clear-state raspberry pi; I didn't install anything and I literally can't given it does not start.

@CoderMike I guess it's 4k - but I run on 1920x1080 (default) - its DELL S2722QC

I see. If there is no problem with the power supply and the SD card, then maybe a hardware issue. I think it's better to contact the seller regarding this matter.

"umap shows amd64 chip" ???
